# Reduce file size in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

Given a CSS/Javascript file where I ony use a small portion of the code (e.g. jquery), is there any way to reduce the file size by removing the unused code?

Comment: Not really. Unless you find out how to statically analyse a dynamically typed language freely in order to map out both a dependency graph of _everything_ (which files rely on which other files and which functions relate to which other functions) and where the control flow goes through. This is a really, really hard problem. Some analysers like Flow do _sort of_ do that but they do need to be guided - you can't really expect that to immediately work if retrofitted to a code-base. So, such a tool does not allow for a free analysis.

Comment: How are you using jquery? One alternative is to search for alternative lightweight libaries that do specifically what you are doing and little else. 

Zepto seems to be a lightweight library that could potentially replace jquery... 
http://zeptojs.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use tools like `https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss` to analyze and remove unused styles.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough information for a great answer; however I have used uncss, https://davidwalsh.name/uncss

You could do run the uncss for your particular usage and save this smaller css file to be used just for your jQuery need. In this situation it would be a child from your main larger CSS file.

All of the CSS files (and javascript) should be minified before using in production.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of `Minify` tool, that will reduce the size